# Jmeter Ant Task - Producing an .xslt report from .jtl file

Tags: xml, xslt, ant, jmeter

So I wanted to produce a .xslt file from a .jtl file in order to generate a summary report

This is the jmeter Ant project I am using:
https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter

From what I understand with jmeter ant, I need to provide a .jmx file to produce a .jtl file. The jtl file that is produced looks similar to a .xml
[image: Jtl file produced my meter Ant]

By default, Jmeter does not structure their .jtl like this. So when I try to generate a report summary, I get a "content is not allowed in prolog" issue, whereas if I provide a .jmx file, every works as expected. The reason why I want to generate a report summary based on only a .jtl is because my .jmx works for multiple scenarios which I need to pass as an argument, so I've only got .jtl files to work with.

Let me know if I can clarify on anything, I feel like I've done a poor job on explaining this issue lmao.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default JMeter stores its results in CSV form which is suitable for generating [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), it might be the case you will find it more informative/usable.

---

If you still want to proceed with the Ant XSLT approach you need to change JMeter result file format to XML, it can be done by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
```

you will need some more default configuration amendments:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
```

This way JMeter will produce the .jtl result files in the format the Ant task will be able to consume and you will be able to perform the XSLT transformation.

More information:

- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)